# Convert list of lists of numbers into a list of lists with the numbers separated by commas

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists like the following one:

```
list = [[226], [44], [8]]
```

I'd like to convert this list of lists into a list of lists where the numbers are separated by commas. Something like this:

```
[[2,2,6], [4,4], [8]]
```

I have been trying to do this using the `split` function. I didn't find a duplicate for this question.

Comment: You can use list comprehension for each integer, like [int(x) for x in str(x)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```py
foo = [[226], [44], [8]]
foo = [eval('[' + ','.join(str(i[0])) + ']') for i in foo]
```

Or this will work:

```py
foo = [[226], [44], [8]]
foo = [[int(n) for n in str(i[0])] for i in foo]
```

Comment: It just prints the first element of each list

Comment: Yes I just tried and it prints first element of each list. Also, on a different note, PEP style advises never use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something simple like this:

`foo = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
print ",".join(foo)
a,b,c`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. This will work even if you have multiple elements in each `sublist` like
 `[[226,542], [44], [8]]`

```
def list_of_list(list):
result = []
for l in list:
    for item in l:
        sub_list= []
        for c in str(item):
            sub_list.append(int(c))
        result.append(sub_list)
return result

print(list_of_list([[226], [44], [8]]))
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 2, 6], [4, 4], [8]]
```